# Is there anyway to have a MySQL insert trigger update a column on the same table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

MySQL does not seem to have very useful error messages, so I’m not sure whether I have a syntax error or this just isn’t possible from an insert trigger.

From a BEFORE INSERT trigger I’m trying to get a value from another table and concatenate it to the “name” column on the row being inserted. Then use that value to update the “unique_name” column on the row being inserted.

It's failing when I attempt to create the trigger with the following error:

```
The following query has failed: 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `trg_insert__tbl_course__build_identifier` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_course` FOR EACH ROW 
SET @user_name := (SELECT tbl_user.username FROM tbl_user WHERE tbl_user.id = new.created_by); 
SET new.identifier = CONCAT(new.name, " (", @user_name, ")");

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET new.identifier = CONCAT(new.name, " (", @user_name, ")")' at line 3
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do that in a BEFORE INSERT trigger. Does it generate an error message? Does it set the wrong value? Is there a row in `tbl_user` matching the condition you searched for?

Comment: Beware of using `“` and `”` use ordinary ascii quotes like `"` or `'` So use a code editor and not a word processor to edit your code

Comment: Thx for the quick responses:  I updated my question with the actual trigger and error.  Also I am using the double quote on my keyboard just to the left of the enter key, that I use for all other string quotations.

Comment: I removed the SET new.identifier line and the trigger created.  Then I put it back and changed the assignment to just and empty string and it failed with the same error.  I then went to the table structure and copied the column name and pasted it in the trigger to insure the column name was correct, same error result.  This is leading me to believe that it is not possible to update a column in the table where the insert is taking place through a trigger.  Although I would have expected a more specific error than a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your syntax is that the semicolon at the end of the first SET statement is interpreted as the end of the CREATE TRIGGER statement. So the second SET statement is not part of the trigger, and you can't reference `NEW.identifier` outside the trigger.

If you have multiple statements in your trigger, this counts as a [compound statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-compound-statements.html), and you must enclose them in a `BEGIN...END` block.

If your trigger has compound statements, then you need to learn how to use DELIMITER to define your trigger. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html